# How to include image in downloading PDF from database on Laravel 8?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, image, pdf

I successfully downloaded the pdf but the image isn't. Instead, it displays "Image not found or type unknown" [The image being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqcba.png). How should I fix it?, I did "myfolder/{{$database->image}}" and my data type in my database is LONGBLOB. The image is visible in loadview but every time I download it "Image not found or type unknown" is displayed. What am I missing? and what should I do? These are the images in my LoadView and PDF [Inside my LoadView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukox0.png) and [the content after I download it as PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8ql8.png)

These are the things I've did and tried.

1. Implementing the PDF

```
Command for install package for PDF :   composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Then go to config/app.php and make some changes

'providers' => [
    ....
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
    ....
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
],
```

2. The image which I've seen and tried from other tutorials/website

```
//The logo which also getting displayed in my LoadView but not getting download as PDF
<img src="assets/images/logo.png">
//The image stored in my folder and database which displays it in my LoadView but doesn't display it or download it together with other data in the PDF
<img height="200" width="200" src="productimage/{{$data->prod_img}}">

//I also did this but it's not being displayed now in my loadview nor every time I download the pdf
<img height="200" width="200" src="{{storage_path('app/public/productimage/$data->prod_img')}}">
```

3. Inside my database the data type before was varchar(255) now I've changed it to LongBLOB [Image of the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcg8W.png)
4. My route **Route::get("/downloadPDF",[EmpController::class,"downloadPDF"]);**
5. The code in my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Receipt;
use PDF;
class EmpController extends Controller
{
    public function getReceipts(){
        $data = receipt::all();
        return view('downloadReceipt', compact('data'));
    }

    public function downloadPDF(){
        $data = receipt::all();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('downloadReceipt', compact('data'))->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'arial']);
        return $pdf->download('data.pdf');
    }
}
```

and the code in my blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/design.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container-scroller">
        <div align="center">
          <img src="assets/images/logo.png">
          
          <h3 class="text-center mt-3">~Customer Receipt~</h3>
            <table id="receptTBL" style="width:100px;">
              <thead>  
                <tr>
                    <th >Product</th>
                    <th >Quantity</th>
                    <th >Paid Amount</th>
                    <th >Total Fee</th>
                    <th >Date</th>
                    <th >Image</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>  
        <tbody>

                @foreach($data as $data)
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>{{$data->prod_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data->prod_qty}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data->paid_fee}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data->total_fee}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data->date}}</td>
                    <td><img height="200" width="200" src="productimage/{{$data->prod_img}}"></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
        </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm so confused. What am I missing? What should I do or try next?

Comment: Instead of <img src="assets/images/logo.png"> - You need to use full path for images. You can use {{ asset('assets/images/logo.png') }}.  Similarly for other image as well.

Comment: thanks, I've tried it but unfortunately the result is still the same. It is displayed in loadview but after I download it as pdf there aren't images.

Comment: try `{{ asset('storage/assets/images/logo.png') }}`

Comment: @maha unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Nothing is displayed in the LoadView as well as downloading pdf

Answer (score 1):

This solved the logo problem,

```
<img src="{{'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path('assets/images/logo.png')))}}">
```

and the ones I am retrieving from mydatabase

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents(base_path('public/productimage/'.$data->prod_img))); ?>" width="120">
```